# Create land surface temperature map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a csv file containing latitude, longitude and temperature for san joaquin valley. I want to plot the latitude and longitude on the y and x axes respectively.I want to use the google base map. The temperature at a particular latitude and longitude should be plotted as a surface map like shown in the image below.
Please guide me to achieve the output as shown in the picture.
      https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8loG.png

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily use ggvis to make the type of map that you want. You will need more than just lat and lon to make it happen if you are looking ot have some kind of color transition based on a prevalence of some kind. It may be in another column and tied to your labeling method.

Here is a solid site to help you get started.

[ggvis mapping](https://rud.is/b/2014/12/29/making-static-interactive-maps-with-ggvis-using-ggvis-maps-wshiny/)

Work through the examples to figure out what is happening beneath the code before you dive right into your own unless you are very familiar with R and the ggvis environment.

Without a starting code base, no one is going to be able to help you more than this...get started and then ask more specific questions.